# ¿Como guardar arrays bidimensional en base de datos?

Tags: php, base-de-datos, array

Haciendo un var_dump de mi formulario obtengo este resultado:

```
       array (size=12)
            'nombre' => string '' (length=0)
            'apellido' => string '' (length=0)
            'dni' => string '' (length=0)
            'telefono_fijo' => string '' (length=0)
            'celular' => string '' (length=0)
            'provincia' => string '' (length=0)
            'ciudad' => string '' (length=0)
            'calle' => string '' (length=0)
            'objetivo_laboral' => string '' (length=0)
            'question' => 
                array (size=2)
                1 => 
                    array (size=5)
                    'empresa' => string '' (length=0)
                    'puesto' => string '' (length=0)
                    'personas_a_cargo' => string '' (length=0)
                    'referencia' => string '' (length=0)
                    'descripcion_puesto' => string '' (length=0)
                2 => 
                    array (size=5)
                    'empresa' => string '' (length=0)
                    'puesto' => string '' (length=0)
                    'personas_a_cargo' => string '' (length=0)
                    'referencia' => string '' (length=0)
                    'descripcion_puesto' => string '' (length=0)
            'institucion' => string '' (length=0)
            'especialidad' => string '' (length=0)
        )
```

Hice una tabla en la base de datos con nombre 'experiencia_laboral', la idea es que cada experiencia se guarde en una fila de la tabla en la db, ya que un mismo usuario puede tener varias experiencias usando una Foreign Key para que se una con la tabla usuarios. Mi pregunta es ¿como debería armar el .php para guardar los arrays?

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con *guardar los arrays*? ¿Acaso quieres guardar los arrays tal cual en una columna de la base de datos? ¿O más bien vas a crear un modelo de datos conforme a los arrays que recibes? ¿O ya tienes ese modelo de datos?... La pregunta no es clara. Sea como sea, ten en cuenta algunos criterios como la *no redundancia de datos*, la *eficacia*  al consultar los datos, etc. Tu array sugiere que se debería implementar un modelo de datos que guarde la información en diferentes tablas...

Comment: Eso que muestro es lo que tengo desde $_post, cree una base de datos con dos tablas: una llamada "datos_user" y la otra "experiencia_laboral. En la tabla "experiencia_laboral" necesitaría guardar la información que viene del índice "question", una fila por acada array. Espero se entienda no se como resolver el problema.. estoy usando MySQL

Comment: Fabricio el índice `question` no tiene ningún dato al menos en el ejemplo que muestras. No le veo mucho sentido a querer guardar un array (vacío), ni tampoco lleno, en una columna. Yo me atrevería a decir que necesitas al menos dos tablas:  una tabla `empresa`, otra tabla `puesto`, de los otros valores no sabría decirte, porque no conozco el contexto pero parece que `descripcion_puesto` formaría parte de una eventual tabla `puesto`. Luego, sería cuestión de usar el array para obtener los ids de cada elemento y llenar una posible tabla relacional solamente con `ids`. Así evitas datos repetidos.

Comment: **Es más, iré + lejos**: leyendo que esos datos vienen de un **formulario** uno hasta podría pensar que estás planteando la lógica al revés. Por ejemplo: ¿qué datos usas para llenar el formulario que genera ese array, **de dónde** tomas esos datos? Podemos hasta imaginar que tu formulario se puede llenar a partir de tablas de tu modelo de datos y luego actualizas lo que tengas que actualizar permaneciendo siempre **en el mismo terreno de tu modelo de datos**. Aquí da la impresión de que has concebido tu formulario como *una cosa aparte* del modelo de datos cuando a lo mejor no debería ser así.

Comment: Utilizo un único formulario dinámico, en el cual dentro del mismo hay una sección que el usuario puede agregar mas de una "experiencia laboral" eso lo controlo con jquery (al hacer click en un boton "+" se agrega una sección con todos esos input dentro del mismo formulario).. y mando los datos al .php por ajax..
Lo que genera esto es que por cada seccion que se agrega en "experiencia laboral" se crea un array que dentro contiene los datos de los input. Por eso dentro de "question" hay arrays que cada uno contiene la información de los input.